# Sqlplus -V in Oracle

Tags: oracle, unix

I'm trying to get Oracle installed.

If I type just sqlplus -V I get this error

```
    Error 6 Initializing SQL*Plus
    Message file sp1<Lang>.msb not found
    SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

However if I type

```
/home/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1/bin/sqlplus -V
```

it works. I then set my PATH, ORACLE_HOME and export them. Everything works.
If I close the terminal and reopen, I'm back to the start with orginal error.

How can I set my PATH and ORACLE_HOME permanently?

Answer (score 3):

In general, in Unix and Unix-like systems, you put commands to set up your environment into a shell-specific file such as `.cshrc` in your home directory.  Which file you should use and what exact commands to include depend on the shell you are using.

In this case, there may be a script provided by Oracle to set up the appropriate environment variables, which you would invoke from your shell setup script.  I am not sure if they provide this on Unix installations, but they do for OpenVMS and I suspect they same would be true on Unix.  If so, I would expect a script with a name similar to `orauser` to exist in the Oracle home directory (/home/oracle/product/11.1.0 in your case).

Comment: When I log in as my Oracle user there is a .profile file. I hardcoded PATH and ORACLE_HOME there. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

type

```
which sqlplus
```

you will notice it is not running from /home/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1/bin